# Unable to find Github Atom editor after installation in Window 7

Tags: atom-editor

I have installed Github's latest Atom editor in Windows 7 and created a html file and all was good.

After that, I closed the Atom editor, and I can't find the editor anymore. I could NOT find it under "All Programs".

Later I checked in the `C:\Users\home\.atom` folder .
There are so many files in that folder, however I am not able to find the executable file.

Please suggest where the executable file shall be placed?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://discuss.atom.io/t/windows-install-location/14100) (fairly old post), it's under or around:

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\atom\app-<version>\atom.exe`

If you can't find your `AppData` directory it may be hidden - just type the path into the Windows Explorer bar and hit enter, or follow the instructions [here](http://www.solveyourtech.com/how-to-find-the-appdata-folder-in-windows-7/).

Edit: [This](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/#platform-windows) official guide cites the same installation location, so if you can't find the program there it may be worth reinstalling. As a last-ditch, try opening the command prompt and entering "atom" - apparently it may have been added to your `PATH` variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Enabled the hidden view option. Could browse to following path C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.18.0\resources\app\node_modules.  however i could not easily find atom.exe file. There is one file called "Update.exe" called under path C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\atom. tried to run Update.exe but editor is not opening.

Comment: you suggested correctly.when i tried to double click on Atom executable file, this time installation just created the missing icon in desktop as well exe and ico files in the following path  _C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\atom_ The issue is solved now. Thank you

Comment: @PraveenPrabhakar If a post solved your problem, consider [marking it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).